# run xcode 5 and iOS7 changes in older version

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5, xcode4.6

We are working as a team and my partner had made changes to support iOS 7 and Xcode 5.

Now the problem is I have installed Xcode 4.6 in my system. His code is not supported in my Xcode. So I am not able to run this project in my system. I don't want to move to Xcode 5.

Is there any other way that I can still run this project in Xcode 4.6 ?

Let me know if you need to know anything else.

Comment: Why you don't want to move to Xcode 5?

Comment: No You can't run the iOS7 project in Xcode 4.6, use Xcode 5 instead.

Comment: @Virussmca Because I am in the middle of some other work and I fear it might break something while updating it and I have to import certificates and configure all the things from scratch. So it's be best If I can run this in 4.6.

Comment: If you do not have xib files then I think you should able to run the app on older version of xcode as well.

Comment: No I don't have a xib files. I am only using storyboards. Still not able to run.:(

Comment: i suggest you to use Xcode 5.

Comment: You can run your existing project in Xcode 5, when you open it for your storyboard it will ask for upgrade to match iOS7 look and i don't think you will break anything.

Comment: seriously, Isn't there any option other than upgrading to Xcode 5?. I thought there would be a way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Tell your friend using Xcode 5.x to change the `Interface builder document -> Opens in` to Xcode 4.6 of your storyboard, to any storyboard file on the project.
[image]

This will enable you to open the project in Xcode 4.6. However i wont recommend you to use Xcocde 4.6.x since apple want you to use Xcode 5.x, actually starting Feb 1 2014 Apple would reject apps that won't be submitted with Xcode 5.x and optimised for iOS 7. Here is a [link](https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=12172013a) to that announcement.

Another thing important to mention is that you won't be able to test the project on iPhone 5s or compile to arm64 (for better performance on supported devices).

Comment: He don't have xib file but he has storyboards. Read carefully

Comment: thanks for this. but what about code he has done for iOS 7 ? currently it gives error.

Answer (score 2):

According to Apple

> Starting February 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App
>   Store must be built with the latest version of Xcode 5 and must be
>   optimized for iOS 7. Learn more about preparing your apps by reviewing
>   the iOS Human Interface Guidelines.

[Apple Announcement](https://developer.apple.com/news/index.php?id=12172013a)

So anyhow you have to change your development to Xcode5. Better start now to change you development environment to Xcode5.

Apple suggests developers to develop with the latest environment. Tats why apple announces the Betas to test our app early when a new OS comes.

Comment: Please read question carefully. It supports iOS7 and it will be submitted from Xcode 5.

Answer (score -2):

I too faced a similar kind of issue. You need to create a new storyboard file with Xcode 4.6 and use that storyboard for further changes. There's no other way to resolve your issue.